# how to solve error of " ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized?"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
con = new SqlConnection (cs);
SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update Stock Set ConfigID = @ConfigID , Quantity = @Quantity ,TotalPrice =@TotalPrice, StockDate =@StockDate ,Where StockID='" +txtStockID.Text+"'");
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConfigID",SqlDbType.Int).Value= txtConfigID.Text;
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQty.Text;
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@TotalPrice", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtTotalPrice.Text;
UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@StockDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dtpStockDate.Value;
con.Open();
UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this error-message understandable, isn't it? However, you have to assign the connection to the `SqlCommand`, either by using the constructor or the property `Connection`:

```
string updateSQL = @"UPDATE Stock Set ConfigID = @ConfigID, 
                                      Quantity = @Quantity,
                                      TotalPrice = @TotalPrice, 
                                      StockDate = @StockDate 
                     WHERE StockID = @StockID";
SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, con);
```

or

```
SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSQL);
UpdateCommand.Connection = con;
```

- Note that i've added a parameter for the `StockID` in the `Where` and removed the last comma before the `Where`.
- Note also that you should close connections when you're finished, therefore you can use the `using`-statement which ensures that it gets disposed/closed even on error:

  ```
  using(var con = new SqlConnection (cs))
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: but when i add it then error is get " incorrect syntax near  keyword 'where'

Comment: @user3864106: because you had a comma after the last assignment before the `Where`. You also should use a aparmeter for the `WHERE StockID=@StockID`.I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> how to solve error of “ ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized?”

By initializing the `Connection` property

```
UpdateCommand.Connection = con;  
UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also you should wrap your connection object with a *using statement* to make sure it is properly disposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the connection to create the command:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
```

This ensures you have a command initialised with the correct connection. You can set the query string using the property `command.CommandText`:

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT foo FROM foo";
```